# res.write not sending big data until res.end() is called after res.write but don't want to end response because it is SSE connection

Tags: node.js, express, server-sent-events

res.write not sending big data (Sending incomplete data) until res.end() is called but I don't want to use res.end because it is an SSE API.
I m using a compression middleware 
***(Node version is 8 )***

```
let output = null, data = result.data, id = result.id, eventName = result.eventName;
            if (typeof data === "object") {
                let result = rm.utils.stringify(data);
                result = result ? result.split(/[\r\n]+/).map(str => 'data: ' + str).join('\n') : '';
                output = (
                    (id ? "id: " + id + "\n" : "") +
                    (eventName ? "event: " + eventName + "\n" : "") +
                    (result || "Not available") + '\n\n'
                );
            }
            res.result = output || data || "";
            res.write(output || data || "");
            res.flush();
            break;
```

Comment: If you are using `express` then why don't you use `res.send()`?

Comment: @Dijkstra because this is an event-stream API

Answer (score -1):

A few things. First of all i think you need to write the headers first by `res.writeHead` before calling `res.write` . Secondly you can't just hold the connection for too long by default because the timeout value is set by the browser. If you don't send any data during that duration the connection will drop. So you need to use `res.writeProcessing`

```
let output = null, data = result.data, id = result.id, eventName = result.eventName;
        if (typeof data === "object") {
            let result = rm.utils.stringify(data);
            result = result ? result.split(/[\r\n]+/).map(str => 'data: ' + str).join('\n') : '';
            output = (
                (id ? "id: " + id + "\n" : "") +
                (eventName ? "event: " + eventName + "\n" : "") +
                (result || "Not available") + '\n\n'
            );
        }
        res.result = output || data || "";
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.write(output || data || "");
        break;
```

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58664002/3808456) to see how you can hold the connection open with res.writeProcessing. Lastly if you want to send events use a websocket for pushing events from the server.

Comment: We are already setting the content type

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 07:52:53 GMT
Server: nginx/1.13.6
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: Node version is 8 so cant use res.writeProcessing